# JS Cross-Domain request with JSONP

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to perform a cross domain call. so i'm using JSONP.
The problem is that the response is not json, but an html.
The request works fine and i see the response with status 200 in the network console, however the error function is the one being called, as the expected response is JSON whereas I get an html.

1. Do you have alternatives for using JSONP for cross domain request?
2. If i'm using JSONP but the request is not, can I somehow expect a value which is not a json? (tried dataType: 'jsonp text' and didn't work)
3. Although I get an error with the ajax call, is there a way to extract the result of the request, as it still returns status 200, it's just not accessible ?

$.ajax
({

```
            type: "GET",
            url: myurl,
             crossDomain:true,
             dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);                                      
            },
            error: function (data) {        
                console.log(data);                 
            },  

 });
```